# Gallery having images of a particular url folder

Tags: multithreading, url, android-asynctask, directory, android-gallery

I'm working on a gallery having images of a particular url folder Android I found a code that works but when i add this code in my project the activity crashes

Here is the Java Code :

```
  package com.dvp.android.gallery;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

/**
 * @author Micka�l Le Trocquer
 */
public class Galeries extends Activity {

    //Adresse o� se trouve l'ensemble des images gif (num�rot�es de 1 � 21).
    private final static String SERVER_IM = "http://10.0.2.2/www/Bardo/images/Galerie/";

    // GUI
    private Gallery gallery;
    private ImageView imgView;

    //Data
    private ArrayList<URL> mListImages;
    private Drawable mNoImage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galeries);

        //R�cup�ration d'une image par d�faut � afficher en cas d'erreur ou de liste vide
        mNoImage = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_photo);

        //Construction des URL pour les images
        mListImages = buildListImages();

        //R�cup�ration du composant affichant l'image en grand
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        //On lui met une image par d�faut (la premiere de la liste ou � d�faut l'image d'erreur)
        if (mListImages.size() <= 0) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(mNoImage); 
        } else {
            try {
                setImage(imgView, mListImages.get(0));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //R�cup�ration du composant affichant la liste des vignettes
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        //On lui donne notre adapter qui s'occup�ra de l'alimenter en vignette
        gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));
        //Espacement entre les vignette
        gallery.setSpacing(10);

        //Lors d'un clic sur une des vignettes, on affiche l'image correspondante en grand
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, final int position, long id) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                try {
                    setImage(imgView, mListImages.get(position));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                     }
                }).start();
            }
        });

    }






    /**
     * Permet de construire la liste des urls pour les images
     * @return
     */
    private ArrayList<URL> buildListImages() {
        int nbTotalImage = 21;
        ArrayList<URL> listFic = new ArrayList<URL>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= nbTotalImage; i++) {
            try {
                listFic.add(new URL(SERVER_IM + "/" + i + ".gif"));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("DVP Gallery", "Erreur format URL : " + SERVER_IM + "/" + i + ".gif");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return listFic;
    }


    /**
     * Notre adapter qui g�re la liste des vignettes
     * @author Micka�l Le Trocquer
     */
    public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
        int GalItemBg;
        private Context cont;

        public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
            cont = c;
            TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
            GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            typArray.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mListImages.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imgView = null;
            //R�cyclage du composant
            if (convertView == null) {
                imgView = new ImageView(cont);
            } else {
                imgView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }
            //On affecte notre image � la vignette
            if (mListImages.size() <= 0) {
                imgView.setImageDrawable(mNoImage); 
            } else {
                try {
                    setImage(imgView, mListImages.get(position));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //On d�fini la taille de l'image
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            //On fixe un arri�re plan plus sympa
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

            return imgView;
        }
    }


    /**
     * M�thode permettant de t�l�charger une image depuis une URL et de l'affecter � un composant de type ImageView
     * @param aView
     * @param aURL
     */
    public void setImage(ImageView aView, final URL aURL) throws IOException {
        final Bitmap bm = null;
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                URLConnection conn = null;
                try {
                    conn = aURL.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    conn.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = conn.getInputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Bufferisation pour le t�l�chargement
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8192);

                // Cr�ation de l'image depuis le flux des donn�es entrant
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                try {
                    bis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        task.execute(null, null, null);
        // Fixe l'image sur le composant ImageView
        aView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
}
```

The logcat output

```
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-171
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:869)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4253)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10539)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10494)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:424)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageView.java:437)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at com.dvp.android.gallery.Galeries.setImage(Galeries.java:231)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at com.dvp.android.gallery.Galeries$1$1.run(Galeries.java:83)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/AndroidRuntime(2016):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-27 17:33:22.719: E/SoundPool(289): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
```

I googled and found no information about this exception. I'm really confused about this problem and don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Post the logcat please

Answer (score 0):

it is clearly written that you are doing network operation on main thread which is not allowed. You can consider using async or can create your own runnables to run in background.
You can use [Universal Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
08-29 10:43:21.756: E/AndroidRuntime(1991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Bardo/com.example.Bardo.Galeries}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: @Bilel have you checked the link i posted? Also the answer clearly states the reason of your error.

Comment: Yes My problem is how to change my code to make it runnable in tow threads I don't know why when i copy it and paste it in my project dosen't work here is the link http://www.developpez.com/telechargements/0c4773731a9d931126730ad638143af4/go/1]

Comment: I tried before but i didn't succeed, there is no a tutorial explain how to use it and my objectif is to load images from url folder in a gallery just help me to fix this code it works in other project but not in my project

Comment: there is a proper explanation even there is a sample app for usage of that lib.